# jQuery - why attr() does not consistently update displayed value on screen

Tags: jquery, html, browser

here's two lines of jQuery

```
$("input[name=displayPrice1]").attr("value", vPrice);
$("input[name=displayPrice1]").val(vPrice);
```

both lines update the value of an input of type text.

here is a fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/fZm7w/

follow these steps:
1. after page load: **click set attr()  -  the empty input will take the value of 150**
2. click on append row and click again on set attr()  -  both input will get at 150
3. change manually the values in both inputs  -  say with 500 and 100
4. **click set attr()  -  none of the values displayed will change**, but the value attribute will change
5. click on set val()  -  both displayed values will be updated but not the attr value, as expected

**Why does set attr() sets the value on screen when the input is empty but not when it has been filled with content by the user?**

Comment: Maybe try to set up a simple demo on jsfiddle.net that shows this happening. It's a bit hard to follow in this form.

Comment: your code is working perfectly fine: http://jsfiddle.net/Saturnix/rAw8J/

Comment: Well , I doubt browsers do such thing. It's working allright.

Comment: yeah, it effectively works fine when out of the page... .val(vPrice) will work too, but .attr('value',vPrice) won't

Comment: if its not youre code, its possible theres some DOM trickey being pulled, IE. another element over the input thats absolutely positioned  to display the inputs value all fancy like....

Comment: just heard about shadow dom.

http://glazkov.com/2011/01/14/what-the-heck-is-shadow-dom/

I can't explain how it really affects this case, but I kinda feel there's something there

Comment: updated question with jsfiddle. I now see I wasn't even sure on what my question was at first, thanks for letting me clear that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.val()` gives the actual value that is in input field

`.attr()` is only getting attribute value in source of input field

Comment: thanks for clearing that out. but how then could changes on the source not affect the screen as in .attr('value',whateverString).
It's hard to put the entire site on jsfiddle, as soon as I can reproduce the problem I'll upload it

Comment: Well. I still don't know why browsers prevent value from being overwrited, but thanks for the precision and your answer.

Comment: attr is getting the objects value when the html is created. val() is getting the object's property value dynamicly.

Comment: please read the question again. the difference between .attr() and .val() is very very clear. what is not is why .attr() will set the value DISPLAYED when input is empty but not when it has been changed by the user.